# Predicting a real valued scalar between $[-1,1]$ given n Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I observe a sequence of $n$ values on $X_k \in \{-1,1\}$ and I want to take the average, that is I want: $Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{K = 1}^n X_k$. The problem is I do not know how to state this formally. $X$ is a Bernoulli variable, $Y$ ranges over $[-1,1]$ and is continuos. How should I state this formally? What is the average operation doing here? Alternatively I could let $X \in [-1,1]$. And suppose I only observe the end points $-1$ and $1$, in this case $Y = X$ and my problems are solved. But this seems a bit intellectually dishonest.

Comment: Do you mean here that the $X_k$ are iid and have the same distribution as $X$? Btw, $Y$ defined like this is not a continuous rv if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yeah apologies the $X_k$ here are iid and have same distibution as X. I will change the notation to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate how $Y$ is distributed ?

Comment: @callculus yes that would be ideal. But for me the first question is how do I justify pulling a real valued $Y$ after observing n discrete trials of random variables.

Comment: What is $P(X_i=-1)$ in your case ?

Comment: $P(X_i = -1) $ should be the number of times $X_i = -1$ over the total number of trials I observe, in the case where $X$ is discrete. For continous $X$ is it not well defined, hence the intellectual dishonesty. The only way the continous case might work is if I say I get a dollar for every head and lost a dollar for every tail, then the question what is the expected payoff. So we have some sort of martingale.

Comment: @callculus just repsoned